# PHP Rewrite htaccess - duplicate content prevention?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^newsite/.*/([0-9]+)$  newsite/content.php?id=$1
```

so http://example.com/newsite/content.php?id=60  can be http://example.com/newsite/anything/60

How do we avoid duplicate urls.

I was thinking "anything" should actually be pulled from page title. Can this be done? and then forced redirect somehow?

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Rewrite rule cannot parse your HTML content.

Comment: 1) read the title from your database 2) remove anything not letters/numbers/space and replace space with underscore or dash 3) use that plus the ID as your link, for example `<a href="http://example.com/title_here/10">Title Here</a>` 4) use your rule to forward that pretty URL to your code, like your example. >> *Side note, you can check the title + id to verify its not coming with the wrong title at your php and properly handle it with for example a 404 response, etc.*